# How to check if array's elements contain specific digit?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, algorithm

I have a task: Implement an `FilterByDigit` method that obtains an array of integers whose elements contain a given digit. Don't use LINQ. The task definition is given in the  XML-comments for this method.

For example, for array { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 68, 69, 70, 15, 17 } => { 7, 70, 17 } for digit = 7.

May be I can use Array.FindAll?

My own idea - is to use cycle and count such elements, then resize array.

```
namespace FilterTask
{
    public static class ArrayExtension
    {
        public static bool IsContainDigit(int element, int digit)
        {
            if (element == 0 && digit == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }

            element = Math.Abs(element);
            while (element != 0)
            {
                if (digit == element % 10)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                element /= 10;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public static int[] FilterByDigit(int[]? source, int digit)
        {
            if (source == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            }

            if (source.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid size");
            }

            if (digit < 0 || digit > 9)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(digit));
            }

            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (IsContainDigit(source[i], digit))
                {
                    ++count;
                }
            }

            int[] answer = new int[count];
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (IsContainDigit(source[i], digit))
                {
                    answer[j++] = source[i];
                }
            }

            return answer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share some code and explain what is not working for you.

Comment: _"Why I can use Array.FindAll?"_ - not following the question. `Array.FindAll` is not a part of LINQ and you can use it if you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your code and show us what you have already tried. Please also consult the following guidelines for how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can i make my code more easilier, may be you can tell me how i can use Array.Findl?

Comment: Any justification for "Don't use LINQ"?  I wonder if the restriction of "Don't use LINQ" is an arbitrary restriction, such as for a school assignment to explicitly preclude the use of any pre-made searching/filtering function such as `Array.FindAll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `Array.FindAll` with your existing function

```cs
var found = Array.FindAll(i => IsContainDigit(i, someDigit));
```

Answer (score 5):

> Can i make my code more easilier, may be you can tell me how i can use Array.FindAll?

Here you are. `Array.FindAll` accepts search predicate and returns array of matching elements.

```cs
var ints = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 68, 69, 70, 15, 17 };
var findAll = Array.FindAll(ints, i1 => i1.ToString().Contains("7"));
```

Also you can check how it is [implemented @source.dot.net](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Array.cs,1037).

P.S.

Your approach seems to be fine also (just verify that it does work as intended).

Answer (score 0):

After counting the elements, you can create a new array of the appropriate size and populate it with the filtered elements.

```
{
    public static class ArrayExtension
    {
        public static bool IsContainDigit(int element, int digit)
        {
            if (element == 0 && digit == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        element = Math.Abs(element);
        while (element != 0)
        {
            if (digit == element % 10)
            {
                return true;
            }

            element /= 10;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static int[] FilterByDigit(int[] source, int digit)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }

        if (source.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid size");
        }

        if (digit < 0 || digit > 9)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(digit));
        }

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (IsContainDigit(source[i], digit))
            {
                ++count;
            }
        }

        int[] answer = new int[count];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (IsContainDigit(source[i], digit))
            {
                answer[j++] = source[i];
            }
        }

        return answer;
    }
}
```

}

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 68, 69, 70, 15, 17 };
int digit = 7;

int[] filteredNumbers = ArrayExtension.FilterByDigit(numbers, digit);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", filteredNumbers));  // Output: 7, 70, 17
```